# Haskell: Exercise problem (Convert Currencies that consist of two seperate Integers)

Tags: haskell

So I got three datatypes Euro, Dollar and Yen. The datatype Currency is one of those.

```
data Euro = MkEuro Integer Integer
data Dollar = MkDollar Integer Integer
data Yen = MkYen Integer
data Currency = MkE Euro | MkD Dollar | MkY Yen
```

Now I wanna convert f.e. Dollar to Euro. Lets say 1 Dollar is 0.90 Euro.

I really dont know how to implement that in Haskell.  I need a function toEuro that takes in a Currency and converts it into Euro and gives it out as a Currency aswell. The problem is that f.e. Dollar und Cents are split into two seperate Integers and Iam not allowed to use any split or connection functions (if there even is some of these). I have no idea how to calculate with two seperate Integers. Lets say I have 12,20 Dollars and I want it as 10,98 Euros. How do I get it into Euros if 1 Dollar was 0.90 Cent. So I need 12 20 to be 10 98. I just dont see it.

Comment: Hint 1: Ignore `Currency` for now and just come up with a function with type `Dollar -> Euro` at first. Hint 2: Think about a function from cents to euro cents instead, e.g., that would convert 1220 cents to 1098 euro cents.

Comment: Auch Info erstsemester an der WWU? xD

Answer (score 0):

> Iam not allowed to use any split or connection functions (if there even is some of these).

It's not clear what you mean by that. I strongly suspect that you're supposed to use [pattern matching](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching#The_connection_with_constructors). Joseph's comment is fine, and possibly helpful, but it sounds like the thing you're missing is how to get the integers you need out of the `Currency`. Try completing this fragment:

```hs
toEuro :: Currency -> Currency
toEuro (MkE e) = MkE e
toEuro (MkD (MkDollar d c)) = let usCents = (100 * d) + c
                              in MkE (MkEuro ... ...)
...
```

Protips:

1. That last ellipsis isn't a mistake, there's a whole line missing.
2. The first pattern seems awkward; we didn't unpack `e` into `MkEuro eE eC`, so why did we have to unpack `(MkE e)`? The answer is because we had to check that it was actually a Euro; obviously we couldn't just write `toEuro e = e`. But a "better" compromise may have been to use an "as" pattern: `toEuro e@(MkE _) = e`.
3. You suggested using 0.9 as a conversion factor; it seems inevitable that you'll want that to be an *argument* to your function. It should be your first argument; in Haskell your "subject" argument, the most "data-like" argument, should always go last. (Configuration arguments come first.) But it's more complicated than that because you also have to worry about Yen. I don't know how you're going to want to handle that...